# Docker don't copy files in .gitignore

Tags: git, docker, google-cloud-platform, gitlab, continuous-integration

In my project, I have to use `docker-in-docker` to upload from GitLab a Google CloudRun using CLoudBuild.
I'm running into a strange error. I have a local version of the `.env`  file that I don't want to be excluded from git revisioning. So I put it in the `.gitignore` file.

But in the CloudBuild upload process, I create a file named `.env` using the variables set into CI/CD of GitLab. I use this `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

```
image: docker:latest

stages:
    - deploy

deploy:
    stage: deploy
    image: google/cloud-sdk
    services:
        - docker:dind
    script:
        - echo CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD=$CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD >> app/.env
        - echo CLOUDSQL_USERNAME=$CLOUDSQL_USERNAME >> app/.env
        - echo CLOUDSQL_HOST=$CLOUDSQL_HOST >> app/.env
        - echo MONGODB_PASSWORD=$MONGODB_PASSWORD >> app/.env
        - echo MONGODB_USERNAME=$MONGODB_USERNAME >> app/.env
        ...
```

The problem is that this file is not copied by docker to the new container and I can't access it in my Node.js app. It seems like docker is incorporating also the lines of `.gitignore` file and excluding the `.env` the GitLab CI has just created.

I've tried to set up the `.dockerignore` file in a whitelist approach.

```
*
#white list
!app/.env
!app/index.js
!app/package.json
!app/service-account.json
!app/yarn.lock
```

and this is the `Dockerfile` being used.

```
FROM node:14.12-alpine3.12

ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS service-account.json

EXPOSE 8080

WORKDIR /app

COPY app/ ./

RUN yarn

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [official docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore) don't say, but from personal experience, if you do not have a `.gcloudignore` file, then it defaults to follow the rules in your `.gitignore`

There is the option to disable this default behaviour globally:

```
gcloud config set gcloudignore/enabled false
```

but that does not sound like a good option. Best is to explicitly add a .gcloudignore file:

```
.gcloudignore
.git
.gitignore

!app/.env
```

The last line would not make a difference in your case, but just including it to show how to explicitly include a missing file.

Comment: I wish I read that days ago! I was desperate not to see my files in the docker container and couldn't figure out why. I would give you 100 upvotes. Thank you!!

Answer (score -3):

As Stefano Moro mentioned, you are missing the `.` in `.env`

docker manages the  `.gitignore` file as a regular file.